# Comparing two LatLng objects in google map v2 android

Tags: java, android, double, latitude-longitude, google-maps-api-2

I have an arraylist which consists of latLong object as shown below:

```
ArrayList < LatLng > latLngList = new ArrayList< LatLng >();
```

**Note: LatLng is an object which has latitude and longitude values in double format i.e., Latitude is in double format and Longitude is in double format**

The below are the values which are stored in the above **latLngList** object:

```
Lat Long List:[lat/lng: (34.072516,-118.403609), lat/lng: (34.074227,-118.399248), lat/lng: (34.07304,-118.3995), lat/lng: (34.07304,-118.3995), lat/lng: (34.07304,-118.3995), lat/lng: (34.067856,-118.401485)]
```

Now, since i am dealing with google map v2 in android, whenever i click on a particular marker i get the latitude and longitude position and i try to compare it with the **latLngList** object to find whether the object is present in the **latLngList**.

I am doing it in the following way:

```
 for(LatLng latLng : latLngList) {
       marker.getPosition().equals(latLng); **Always returns false**
 }
```

The marker position is returning me with the following latLng object:

```
lat/lng: (34.074226888265116,-118.39924816042185)
```

It is clear that the latitude and longitude object returned by marker is a bit lengthy and hence the comparison fails.

Is there a better way of comparing the latLng object?

Answer (score 6):

A better way is not to compare markers based on `LatLng`, but on the identity of `Marker`. For some weird reason `Marker.getPosition()` doesn't return exactly the same value.

I'd suggest storing all markers in a `List` or `Map` if you want to attach some additional info to every `Marker`.

Alternatively you may use `Marker.getId()` after you create `Marker`, store it and later compare that in `onMarkerClick`.

**Edit:**

I have also reported this on [gmaps-api-issues](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5353).

Comment: HashMap<Marker, LatLng> also does the job

Answer (score 4):

Implement latlngs like this. this worked for me.

```
final LatLng[] latLngs = new LatLng[2];
latLngs[0] = new LatLng(lat, lng);
latLngs[1] = new LatLng(lat, lng);

if(latLngs1[0].equals(latLngs1[1])) {
//to do 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that the best way is to calculate the distance between your latlng point and markers points, using the static [Location](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween%28double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float%5B%5D%29) method.
You can deal with returned distance in meters, and decide if is the same point aproximately.

Comment: You can order your ArrayList by distance from Marker position. Just implements Comparable interface, so first item of ArrayList is the nearest one.

Comment: what? you will need to reorder them every time when clicking different markers, so performance will get only worse — from O(n) to O(n*log(n))

Comment: You are right for sure, performance is really bad. I use it just for getting the nearest point from an ArrayList to a LatLng.

Answer (score 0):

I want to clarify Maciej's answer a bit, because the question title tells about comparing `LatLng` objects. `LatLng` objects are, by themselves, perfectly equatable — their `equals` and `hashCode` semantics are correct. ([and the docs say this, too](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLng#equals%28java.lang.Object%29))  It's only the `Marker` bug that the `Marker`'s store their positions not accurately.
So if you indeed want to keep track of precise `Marker` positions, you can simply store all added markers in a `HashMap<Marker, LatLng>`. But if you want just to compare two markers, don't use their positions at all, a simple `Marker.getId()` will do the job, as MaciejGórski said.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options i can think of, one is using the quadtree library: http://koti.mbnet.fi/ojalesa/quadtree/quadtree_intro.htm which is easy to use and ver helpful, the other is a very good answer by @geocodezip (in javascript)

```
var SameThreshold = 0.1;
if (google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(latlng1,latlng2) < SameThreshold)
marker1.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
```